# Azure DevOps Pipeline PostSharp failure on linux VM

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, postsharp

I had planned to move my DevOps Pipeline to linux vm. Unfortunately, I faced with this problem. I am using Postsharp 6 on my `.Net Core 2.2` project.

```
Build FAILED.

/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/postsharp/6.1.18/build/PostSharp.targets(148,5): error MSB4062: The "PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharpValidateLanguageVersion" task could not be loaded from the assembly /home/vsts/.nuget/packages/postsharp/6.1.18/build//net471/PostSharp.MSBuild.v6.1.18.Release.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Core.csproj]
/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/postsharp/6.1.18/build/PostSharp.targets(148,5): error MSB4062: Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Core.csproj]

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostSharp doesn't work on Linux VM.

The only solution is using `Windows Server` on yaml. Even Selenium removed Postharp support.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

You can look at the pictures to understand the steps better.

[image: yaml configuration]
[image: success on windows server]

---

- Update

**PostSharp 6.3.5 preview** version supports Linux and macOS builds.

Also, you can create a docker image too. I am using these images:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
```

Comment: To be exact, PostSharp supports build on Windows only, but the resulting assembly can be executed on Linux as well.
Support for build on Linux is on the roadmap with a high priority.